# Multiple comparisons on an array of ints

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of ints

```
mypos = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

and a list of start & end positions, like this:

```
mydelims = [[5, 12],
            [15,31],
            [12,16],
            [22,69]]
```

I'd like to loop through `mydelims` and count how many positions are within each pair. Instinctively, I would write it like this:

```
for mypair in mydelims:
    print(sum(mypos>mypair[0] & mypos<mypair[1]))
```

However, python doesn't seem to handle this. I know `mypos>42` will return an array of booleans, but what is the most efficient way to apply multiple comparisons to one array of ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close and looking for `np.logical_and`:

```
import numpy as np

mypos = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

mydelims = [[5, 12],
            [15, 31],
            [12, 16],
            [22, 69]]

result = {
    tuple(mypair): sum(np.logical_and(mypos > mypair[0], mypos < mypair[1])) 
    for mypair in mydelims
}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{(5, 12): 1, (15, 31): 2, (12, 16): 0, (22, 69): 3}
```

Note that you're treating the delims as non-inclusive - which I assumed was intentional. I.e. neither `5` nor `12` fall within `[5, 12]`.